# Can I connect my android application with a database on my pc?

Tags: android, sql, database

So I basically want the database on my pc to be accessed through my android application, (on multilple android devices at max 3), doesnot matter if not connected to internet just need that for my college project.

Comment: you better use [sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) for offline database but it will store only single mobile data you can not connect with other mobiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous answers have mentioned, it's not advised to connect directly to a database from an android application and use of a web service would be better suited for this purpose.

However, if this is absolutely necessary you can use the JTDS drivers for android which will allow you to connect to either a local database hosted on your machine, or a database hosted elsewhere.

Links to the drivers can be found [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

It shouldn't be too hard to find a tutorial on how to add the driver to your project however if you struggle to find anything, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be done with a REST api, then it would make HTTP calls to the backend which accesses the database either located on a server or in this case your pc. However accessing the database directly is not advised.